# Iptables sniffing traffic not sent to local machine

Tags: iptables, mirror, sniffer

I have a switch configured to mirror all traffic to an ethernet interface of a server. I can actually see the packets received with tshark, tcpdump, etc, but iptables doesn't seem to see this traffic. My ultimate goal is to ulog syn packets for connection accounting.

I tried to place rules in PREROUTING chain, unsuccessfully.

Can iptable capture packets not sent to the local machine? If no, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Which table do you use for monitoring?

What you want to do is to use the filter table (the default one) and the `FORWARDING` chain: it is specifically designed to capture packets which "traverse" the machine. For instance:

```
iptables -A FORWARDING -p tcp --dport 80 -j LOG
```

The `INPUT` chain will capture packets from the outside destined to the local machine, and the `OUTPUT` chain will capture packets originating from the machine and going outside.

One side note: packets transiting through loopback go through both `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains.

As to `PREROUTING`, it is a chain meant to modify packets, if necessary, *before* the routing decision -- this is why, for instance, port redirection is done in there. And this is why the filter table has no hook in it: it does not make sense.

Comment: The thing is, even 

    iptables -A (FORWARD or INPUT) -i eth1 -p tcp -j ULOG

doesn't see anything.

Comment: Then it is very probable that either your rule is wrong (wrong interface?) or packets don't do what you think they do... More details look necessary.

Comment: tcpdump -i eth1 gives me a lot of packets per second, but simple rules like  
iptables -I (INPUT or FORWARD) 1 -eth1 -j ULOG  
has a zero in the matched packets column.  
The same rules with interfaces receiving "real" traffic work great.

Comment: Try the `LOG` target instead? It looks like a network bizzarerie here, please post details about the configuration (output of `ip link`, `ip addr`, etc).

Comment: ip link: `4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000 link/ether d0:67:e5:e5:88:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` ip addr: `4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000 link/ether d0:67:e5:e5:88:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet6 fe80::d267:e5ff:fee5:8841/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: [I've found someone searching for the same thing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1333554).  
Do you think ebtables could be useful?

Comment: ebtables is for bridging. So, if you use bridging the answer could be yes. On another note, have you asked your question on superuser? It looks like a more appropriate place for it. I am afraid I am out of ideas at this point :/

Comment: @yapakmoi it is another stackexchange site focusing on OS related problems

Answer (score 0):

`iptables` will only work with IP packets somehow directed at your machine. So what you are trying to achieve will *not* be doable with `iptables`. For it to work would require that you set up your accounting machine as a router for all IP traffic.

What’s wrong with tcpdump for this task?

```
tcpdump -G 3600 -w tcpsyn-%FT%T.pcap tcp and 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-ack|tcp-syn) = tcp-syn'
```

If you want all TCP initiation attempts.

```
tcpdump -G 3600 -w tcpsynack-%FT%T.pcap tcp and 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-ack|tcp-syn) = (tcp-ack|tcp-syn)'
```

If you want all TCP sessions actually established.

Comment: I want to log and graph the number of TCP connections to a set of IP subnet. I intend to use iptables and ulogd instead of tcpdump because I don't want to run tcpdump full time.

Comment: @yapakmoi I understand your first point. I am pretty sure that bare `iptables` won’t do the job *unless* you change your network topology. Finally I still fail to understand why you “don't want to run tcpdump” although it would fulfill your requirements.